# Using a custom UIPresentationController with horizontally compact UITraitCollection, but a popover otherwise

Tags: ios, uikit, uipresentationcontroller

I have a view controller that I'm presenting in a universal iOS application. On the iPhone, it displays using a custom UIPresentationController which adjusts the frame of the presented view using `UIPresentationController`'s `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView` method. This is working fine, however...

On iPad, I'd like the same view controller to display as a popover when the `UITraitCollection` has a `Regular` width, but to switch to my custom UIPresentationController when in `Compact` width. Is this achievable?

Comment: how would you transition between the two on rotation? remove and replace?

Comment: @ndg : Wht do you mean by compat width availabel in ipad ?? You mean in portrait orientation ???

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible.Straight from Apple's ["What's new in iOS8 guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html)

> With the amount of screen space available, the iPad has a regular size class in the vertical and horizontal directions in both portrait and landscape orientations.

[image]